# Do VBA "constructors" and "destructors" (namely Class_Initialize and Class_Terminate) support access to Me (i.e. this)?

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop, ms-word

From my understanding, VBA programmers often refer to Class_Initialize and Class_Terminate as "constructor" and "destructor". However, it turns out that I can't even use Me to access the class methods in these constructor and destructor. Is it normal?

For example:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Call Me.Init(...)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Call Me.Deinit(...)
End Sub
```

And also:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call Me.Init(...)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Call Me.Deinit(...)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just `Call Init(...)` should do (or omit the `Call` keyword - `Init ...`)

Comment: Are the `Init` and `Deinit` methods public or private? If private, you cannot use `Me` as they are not publicly exposed. Anyways, as shown above - just call `Init` without the brackets.